# How do I determine if a button was clicked or not but in the previous page?

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say I have a start.php and it contains 2 buttons, both buttons if clicked lead to result.php

How can I know which button was clicked being on result.php?

Because I need to load a function once the result.php is loaded and based on what user clicked.

Thank you!

Comment: you should have to show us what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via javascript.

If you are using some form submission then you can do it as :

Take some hidden field to get values of the button clicked. When button1 click enter button1 value in that hidden field and if button2 clicked then add the value button2 and you will get these values on result page.

If you are doing some other flow please let me know

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm doing it via JS, can you please give me an example?

Comment: You are going on result page using form submission?

Answer (score 0):

You can code like this

```
<form action="result.php" method=get>
    <input type=hidden value="button1" name="whichbutton">
    <input type=submit value="Button1">
</form>
<form action="result.php" method=get>
    <input type=hidden value="button2" name="whichbutton">
    <input type=submit value="Button2">
</form>
```

then you know which button was clicked by reading $_GET["whichbutton"]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
function clicked(val){
 alert(val);
 window.location = '/result.php?page=' + val;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick='clicked(this.value);'>
<input type="button" value="button2" onclick='clicked(this.value);'>
```

And in the result page, you can use $_GET['page'] to check